# Use new value in after trigger sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a trigger that will dump out a csv file of data at a certain point in an application. When you create a payment order from a payment proposal then it means it is ready to be paid and uploaded to the bank. There is a wizard in the erp that makes the payment order from the payment proposal. There is also a header and a detail table on both proposals and orders. I need it to make it when there is a new row in the payment order table that has new.way_id = 'ACH' and new.institute_id = 'BMO'.

The problem is the wizard has multiple steps and doesn't insert the detail rows for the order till the last step when you click ok, but the header is created already before this and executes the trigger. Because of this when the header is created I am going to pull all of the data from the proposal header and detail because it is all already there.

When The trigger executes it makes a sql statement and then passes it to a stored procedure that will take any sql query and dump it to a csv file. For some reason it won't let me use the new reference when I create my query. I get an error saying "new.selected_proposals invalid identifier". I need it to do a like on this also because you can select multiple proposal header id's when you create an order and I only want it to do it for the ones from the proposals that have a way_id of ACH.

I am guessing I have to add the .new table, whatever it is, into the join or something, but I am not sure how to do that.

This is Oracle database 11g. Here is the code. The commented out section in the query is what I am trying to fix, just to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
create or replace TRIGGER CREATE_BMO_ACH_FILE 
AFTER INSERT ON PAYMENT_ORDER_TAB
for each row
when (new.way_id = 'ACH' and new.institute_id = 'BMO')
declare sql_ varchar(4000);
BEGIN
sql_ := q'[select pp.company, pp.Proposal_id, pp.CREATION_DATE, pl.identity, pl.payee_identity, pl.ledger_item_id, pl.currency, pl.curr_amount, pl.GROSS_PAYMENT_AMOUNT, pl.PLANED_PAYMENT_DATE, pl.Order_Reference, pl.PAYMENT_REFERENCE 
   from payment_proposal pp, PROPOSAL_LEDGER_ITEM pl
    where pp.company = pl.company
    and pp.proposal_id = pl.proposal_id
    and pp.way_id = 'ACH'
    /*and pp.proposal_id like '%' || new.selected_proposals || '%'*/]';

  dump_sql_to_csv( sql_, 'E:\Accounting', 'test.csv');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your just missing a colon in front of the new i.e. use `:new.selected_proposals`. Colons aren't required for `old` and `new` in the `WHEN` but are in the code block.

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem. I also needed to get it out of the quotes section. Have it as this now " and pp.proposal_id = ]' || :new.selected_proposals; " and it works. Still trying to figure out the like. Was trying this " and pp.proposal_id like '%' ]' || :new.selected_proposals || q'['%']'; " , but I get an error saying sql command not properly ended.

Comment: Actually I think I will just leave it as that because the like won't work as I expected. This way it will only work if they select 1 proposal, which is the way they should it anyway. There is no need to ever do multiple proposals for one payment order.